# Should Manage Groups display the Smart Group contact count, or just display it as Unknown

Tags: smartgroups, core

When I run Manage Groups, the Smart Group contact count comes up as Unknown for each group.  Clicking the *Update Smart Group Counts* link appears refreshes the group list, but still returns *Unknown*. This is after running the Refresh Smart Group cache job manually. [CRM-21583](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21583) refers to this issue, but has been resolved as *Won't Do* as it seemed to have been related to an addin.  We don't have that addin in our Joomla systems, but still have the issue.

My question is whether *Update Smart Group Counts* is supposed to update the counts displayed in *Manage Groups* or whether [CRM-21583](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21583) should be resurrected?

Comment: The text `unknown` was basically done to avoid the slow loading of the `Manage Group` page. See the `Before` and `After` explanation on the [patch submitted](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11033) for [this issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21229).

Comment: The Update Smart Group Counts link appears to serve no useful purpose.  Even after running the Rebuild Smart Group Cache scheduled job, that link still returns Unknown for the counts of the smart groups, so it might as well be removed and instead of Unknown simply have a dash for the count of smart groups as that count will never be displayed in Manage Groups.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was solved very simply, you just need a non-zero smart group cache timeout for the problem to go away.

Comment: Details here - https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/smart-groups/#smart-group-caching